# simple inequality need to know how it's obtained

Tags: real-analysis

A First Course in Mathematical Analysis - D. Brannan.
Rules added as they may be needed.
Reciprocal Rule Page 10.
For any positive $a,b$ $a < b \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b}$

Power rule: page 10.
for any non-negative  $a,b$ and $p > 0$ 
$a < b \Leftrightarrow {a^p} < {b^p}$.

page 59. 
Deduce: $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }  {a^{{\textstyle{1 \over n}}}}  = 1$
Soln.
If $a > 1$ we can write
 $a = 1 + c$ where $c > 0$. Then
$1 \le {a^{1/n}} = {(1 + c)^{{\textstyle{1 \over n}}}} \le 1 + \frac{c}{n}$ for $n = 1,2,...$ The soln. continues...
Please explain how (from the book) we get LHS inequality ($1 \le {a^{{\textstyle{1 \over n}}}}$).

Comment: $1 < a \implies 1^{1/n} =1  < a^{1/n}$

Comment: but that is not the inequality there is equality too. Please also add which rule from his book you are using.

Comment: are you saying that $1 < a \Rightarrow 1 \le a$

Comment: If the statement $P$ is true, then the statement $P \lor Q$ is also true. So if $a<b$ ($a$ is less than $b$) is true, then $a \leq b$ ($a$ is less than or equal to $b$) is also true. $<$ is simply a stronger condition than $\leq$.

Comment: If you ask me "${(1 + c)^{{\textstyle{1 \over n}}}} \le 1 + \frac{c}{n}$ for $n=1,2, \ldots$" seems suspect. Rigorously speaking, this bit requires a proof by induction.
https://imgur.com/GAVJGCa

Comment: Nope - just Bernoulli: $(1+c/n)^n \ge 1+n(c/n) = 1+c$.

Comment: @martycohen: Bernoulli and binomial (theorem, that is)!

Comment: @Robert Lewis: Don't need binomial theorem. Bernoulli proved by simple induction without it.

Comment: I am aware of Bernoulli's inequality. I was just looking for an in to share some old scratchwork. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take $p = n$.

We want to show that

$a^{1/n} \ge 1, \tag 0$

right?  Well, if not, then

$a^{1/n} < 1, \tag 1$

the given power rule implies

$a = (a^{1/n})^n < 1^n = 1, \tag 2$

which contradicts the hypothesis $a \ge 1$.  Therefore,

$a^{1/n} \ge 1. \tag 3$

We turn to the inequality

$(1 + c)^{1/n} < 1 + \dfrac{c}{n}; \tag 4$

from the binomial theorem,

$1 + c = 1 + n\dfrac{c}{n} < (1 + \dfrac{c}{n})^n; \tag 5$

now use the power rule with

$p = \dfrac{1}{n}; \tag 6$

we find

$(1 + c)^{1/n} = (1 + n\dfrac{c}{n})^{1/n} < 1 + \dfrac{c}{n}, \tag 7$

as required.